# Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I can not fix this error:

```
$match[1] = preg_replace('/(?<=^|[a-z])./e', 'strtoupper("\0")', strtolower(trim($match[1])));
```

How to change it?

Comment: The error tells you exactly what to do. You are familiar with the PHP Manual, yes?

Comment: Yes, I tried: [php]$match[1] = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|[a-z])./', create_function('$x', 'strtoupper("\0"); return strtolower(trim($x[1]))'), $match[1]);[/php]

Comment: The create_function syntax is pretty redundant now - inline anonymous functions are much more natural - see the answer below.

Answer (score 5):

You should read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). The `e` modifier is deprecated and will be removed in further versions.
Just use `preg_replace_callback` (the message told you..)

```
$match[1] = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|[a-z])./', function($m) {
    return strtoupper($m[0]);
}, strtolower(trim($match[1])));
```

Comment: I used your answer to answer my own question. I noticed you didn't get credit for it here, so if you're still active, post it on [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443520/how-do-i-convert-this-create-function-call-to-an-anonymous-function/64443654#64443654) and I'll mark your answer as correct.