# How do I convert this `create_function` call to an anonymous function?

Tags: php, deprecated

I've got some code that uses `create_function`, which is now deprecated. The comments for `create_function` say `* @deprecated 7.2 Use anonymous functions instead.`

This is the function itself: `create_function ('$matches', 'return strtoupper("\0");')`

And this is the context:

```
$match[1] = preg_replace_callback('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./',
                    create_function ('$matches', 'return strtoupper("\0");'), strtolower(trim($match[1])));
```

My code isn't running because it's been deprecated, so I want to turn it into an anonymous function instead. I'm not entirely sure what this bit of code does, so I don't really have a reliable way of testing it, but I THINK that create_function block can be replaced with

```
function($matches) {
    return strtoupper($matches);
}
```

Would that work? Does that do the same thing that the `create_function` function does? I'm not sure what `"\0"` does in that context, so I'm hoping I can get some advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar question another place and tried the answer there. Turns out it's equivalent to this function:

```
function($m) {
   return strtoupper($m[0]);
}
```

Found it here: [Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33539495/deprecated-preg-replace-the-e-modifier-is-deprecated-use-preg-replace-call/33539568)

thanks to [@Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043150/philipp)